# Where do I reach Japanese locals online?

Tags: online-resources, japan, local-knowledge

I'm looking for a forum or similar where I can ask question like "Does this store still exist in Akashi, Hyōgo?" or "How is the selection of kitchenware in the mall in X?". Often I am wondering about places with little to no information online. But some locals should know, for example, that a shop closed down last year. Japanese language would be fine, I can probably manage to get my point across. Any suggestions?

Motivation: There are a lot of second-hand stores in Japan and you never know what kind of selection they have. It would be great to have an idea about whether they are worth seeking out.

Comment: There are probably dozens of major Japanese forums/chats/social networks. Off the top of my head: Travel.SE itself has a few Japanese residents, Couchsurfing forums, Facebook groups.